# sqlite python upload ftp

Tags: python, sqlite, ftp

I'm trying to upload sqlite database file ext *.db
i'm using a simple Python code to do so using Ftplib.
i upload any kind of file using this script BUT when i'm uploading the DB file 
it corrupted while upload some how..
I'm opening it in a "rb" mode.
Will be glad for help
PYthon FTP script Code:

```
ftp = ftplib.FTP(server,timeout=2)
    ftp.login(username, pass)
    ftp.cwd("public_html")
    try:
        newfile=open(filename,"rb") """ ---> filename ="data.db"  """
    except: 
        print "Error not such file or whatever"
        exit()
    ftp.storlines("STOR " +filename , newfile)
    newfile.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

OK.. So after 2 days of trying anything i figure the Very simple answer..
i should used

```
ftp.storbinary("STOR " +filename , newfile)
```

and NOT

```
ftp.storlines("STOR " +filename , newfile)
```